# sql server stored procedure spatial data

Tags: sql-server

I am new to Spatial data types and SQL server as well, I have the following tables:

- Table (A) `ZipCodesUSA`

  - Columns: `zipcodes| latitude| longitude| city| state`
- Table (B) `US_Cities_longitude_Latitude`

  - Columns: `ID int| City nvarchar(40)| Coordinates GEOGRAPHY|`

What I am trying to do is to create an SPROC to transfer all data from table `A` to `B` and change to GEOGRAPHY, once by state. It does changes, but only 1 row for each state. Why? I didn't specify `SELECT 1` or anything. Thank you in advance!

```
ALTER PROC dbo.USA_Cities
@StateAbbr NVARCHAR(2)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @City NVARCHAR(30)
    DECLARE @Longitude NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @Latitude  NVARCHAR(50)

    SELECT  @City = City, @Longitude= Longitude,@Latitude= Latitude 
    FROM ZipCode
    WHERE StateAbbr = @StateAbbr


    INSERT INTO dbo.US_Cities(City, Coordinates)
    VALUES(@City, geography::Point(ISNULL(@Longitude, ''),ISNULL(@Latitude, ''), 4326))

END;


EXEC dbo.USA_Cities 'NY'
```

Comment: What is that 'geography::' method known as and where can I find the documentation for the rest of them? Are they convenience methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code:

```
SELECT  @City = City, @Longitude= Longitude,@Latitude= Latitude 
FROM ZipCode
WHERE StateAbbr = @StateAbbr;
```

Only fetches one row per state -- not all rows for a state.  You need to either put this into a loop, or replace the `select` and `insert` with:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.US_Cities(City, Coordinates)
    SELECT  @City = City,
            geography::Point(ISNULL(Longitude, ''), ISNULL(Latitude, ''), 4326)
    FROM ZipCode
    WHERE StateAbbr = @StateAbbr;
```

Comment: Don't recommend the loop (RBAR).

Comment: ERROR MESSAGES:A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: An INSERT statement cannot contain a SELECT statement that assigns values to a variable.

Comment: thank you Gordon Linoff for replay, you are right it gives me only 1 row, but I still get this error and stucked again :(

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROC [dbo].[USA_CitiesModified]
    @StateAbbr NVARCHAR(2)
AS
BEGIN

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;     

INSERT INTO dbo.US_Cities(City, Coordinates)
SELECT  City, geography::Point(ISNULL(Longitude, ''),ISNULL(Latitude, ''), 4326)
FROM dbo.ZipCode
WHERE StateAbbr = @StateAbbr
```

END;

WORKS GREAT, THANK YOU!